# NameError uninitialized constant Aws::SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am using a Rails code (using AWS SDK) to do the following:

1. Upload a file to an S3 bucket

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    access_key_id: <my key>,
    secret_access_key: <my secret key> 
   )
s3.put_object(bucket: <my bucket>, key: <file name>, body: <file content>)
```

2. Send an email to the user stating that the file has been uploaded to S3 bucket

```
ses = Aws::SES::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2')
```

While step 1 works perfectly fine, I am getting this error when I try to instantiate the SES client in step# 2:

```
NameError uninitialized constant Aws::SES
```

Why `AWS::Ses` is giving a namespace error while `Aws::S3` is working perfectly fine? Please help!

These are the related gems I am using:

```
aws-ses
aws-sdk-3
```

Comment: i guess gem is 'aws-sdk-ses' not aws-ses

Comment: @LHH - Thanks for your help! I added `aws-sdk-ses` to Gemfile and the error is gone now. Would you like to add this as an answer please?

Comment: i have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add gem `'aws-sdk-ses'`

for more info check here https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-ses/versions/1.6.0

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks much for your help!